# Convert Date data type on Bigquery string to date

Tags: date, google-bigquery

Hi all I am trying to convert my data from string to date so I can do date_trunc for cohort analysis.

My data is in string type and the formatting for date looks like this: 20221101

I tried parse_date but with no luck. keep getting error: Mismatch between format character '/' and string character '2' at string index: 2 with format: '%d/%m/%Y'

Comment: `SELECT PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', '20221101') AS mydate;` if the data isn't in that format it returns NULL

Answer (score 0):

If all the data is formatted like: 2022 (year) + 11 (months in 2 characters*) + 01 (day in 2 characters):

-> Use PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', `__your_date_column__`).

Noted: (2 characters* means: November is 11 and January is 01 not 1)